# Wired internet has stopped working

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, wired

I don't really know anything about this stuff, but I was playing Steam, and then I noticed that it showed me as being offline. So I exited the game and saw that my internet was not working. It tries to connect but fails. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04ltp. I'm currently using a wired internet connection through powerline.

Comment: have you tried rebooting, if so, can you give the output of `rfkill list`

Comment: In terminal, type `lshw -C net` and edit your question to include the resultant output. I need to know what ethernet hardware and driver that you're running to make a proper recommendation. Cheers, Al

Comment: If nothing changed in your system it could be also a failure due to your ISP. have you checked the LED's at your router?